# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to produce the following HTML dynamically:

```
<ul>
   <li>Butter Extra</li>
   <li>Butter Extra</li>
</ul>
```

I was trying it this way:

```
var toppingval = 'Butter Extra,Butter Extra';

if (toppingval.indexOf(",") > 0)
{
    var array = toppingval.split(',');
    var uitaghtml = '<ul>' +
    for (var z = 0; z < array.length; z++) 
    {
        '<li>' + array[z] + '</li>' +
    }
    '</ul>';
}
```

But when I tried this it throws an exception in console as

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
```

Could anybody please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: jQuery != Javascript. This is a *Javascript* error. And I'm guess that you're line beginning with `'<li>` are what it's complaining about. Where is what it is being set to (e.g., variable, some property, etc.)? Why does it end in `+`?

Comment: `for` loops don't really "expand" into valid source code like this. You need to append onto `uitaghtml`.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to concatenate a `for` loop to a string.  That is not a thing.  Make a new variable that you continuously append to in your `for` loop.

```
var toppingval = 'Butter Extra,Butter Extra';

if (toppingval.indexOf(",") > 0) {
  var array = toppingval.split(',');
  var uitaghtml = '<ul>';
  for (var z = 0; z < array.length; z++) {
    uitaghtml = uitaghtml + '<li>' + array[z] + '</li>';
  }
  uitaghtml = uitaghtml + '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me , why the condition if (toppingval.indexOf(",") > 0)  is not getting fired ?

Comment: It is being fired.  If you run `toppingval.indexOf(",") > 0` through your console, it will return true.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something you cannot. Syntactically, you cannot leave open a appending operator `+` - which you are trying to do, but adding in `li`'s into your `ul`. Try this:

```
var uitaghtml = $('<ul></ul>');
for (var z = 0; z < array.length; z++) 
{
 uitaghtml.append($("<li>" + array[z] + "</li>"));
}
```